ICS on Windows 10 host with IPv6
My ethernet interface is connected to the internet (dual stack, has both IPv4 and IPv6), and I want to use ICS to share the internet connection to another interface.
When enabled, my non-internet iface gets an DHCPv4 address in the 192.168.137.0/24 subnet, and can reach the internet via the internet-connected iface as gateway (192.168.137.1).
However, the non-internet iface does not get any IPv6 address: Neither a DHCPv6, nor a SLAAC.
Am I setting up something wrong, or is ICS simply not working for IPv6?

There are a few ways to share IPv6, and AFAIK none of them are implemented by Windows:

Obtain a new global /64 prefix through DHCPv6-PD and do regular IPv6 routing. This is how your main router obtains its current LAN prefix – but many home routers don't support "nested" prefix delegation, so your PC usually cannot ask your main router to get a dedicated prefix for itself.

Assign a private prefix and do IPv6 NAT, just like it's done with IPv4. As far as I know, Windows does not implement IPv6 NAT (which is why WSL2 doesn't have IPv6), and really it would kind-of defeat the purpose of IPv6 anyway.

Duplicate the "Internet side" prefix and do "NDP proxying" (the IPv6 equivalent of proxy-ARP). As far as I know, Windows doesn't implement this either. It would technically work but it's still definitely a hack – same result as if you had just bridged the interfaces together, but with more hacks to make it work.


(That is to say, Windows does support pure IPv6 routing – I've used a WinXP PC as my main IPv6 router in the past – it's the need for a dedicated /64 that is the main problem here.)
So although I can't be 100% sure that ICS is IPv4-only (though I'm 90% sure on the grounds of WSL being IPv4-only), I would still suggest just bridging the interfaces together (i.e. turning your PC into an Ethernet switch) – the option is still there in ncpa.cpl when you select two or more interfaces.

I've been having some difficulty to configure the bridging correctly. I'm working on my W10 PC and I want to bridge my ethernet interface (with internet access) to my RNDIS interface. In that way, rndis devices that connect to my PC could have internet access.
However after bridging, my PC no longer has internet access, and the only interface I see in ipconfig is the Network Bridge, which has an autoconfigured (169.xxx.xxx.xxxx) IPv4, and an IPv6 LLA. What could cause this?
I also tried setting the bridge IP addresses statically, and it also did not work.

I'm guessing that RNDIS is the problem, as it's often used in a not-quite-100%-Ethernet manner. Where does the other end go – USB 4G modem? Android tethering?

I completely removed the RNDIS interface from the bridge, so that only the Ethernet interface remains on the bridge. The behaviour is the same: The Ethernet interface does not show up anymore in ipconfig, and in its place I get the bridge interface with the autoconfigured addresses. I also don't have internet access anymore.
